# Cannot find media file in directory in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, command-line

I am trying to simply play an MP3 sound (which I have included in the project directory under "files" folder). This is the snippet I used:

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import Cocoa
import Speech


var sound = AVAudioPlayer()
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "this", ofType: "mp3")

do {
    sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)) //line 19
}
catch {
    print("ERROR")
}
sound.play()
```

File name is "this.mp3". The problem occurs on line 19 with error being "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file" I read about this error so I think somehow my program is not able to find the file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First, post code, not a screen-shot of code. Second, set a breakpoint and step through your code. Inspect the value of `path`. If it is nil, make sure you added your `this.mp3` file to your target.

Comment: Hello, I checked and it appears that the value of path is nil although this.mp3 already exists in files folder of project directory.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 3**

After comments clarified the OP is writing a `Command Line Application` ...

Make sure your audio file is included like this:

[image]

Then, (very simplified) example test code could be:

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

class AudioTest {

    var sound = AVAudioPlayer()

    func testMP3() -> Void {

        let bundle = Bundle.main
        let url = bundle.url(forResource: "files/this", withExtension: "mp3")
        if let u = url {

            do {
                sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: u, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)
                sound.prepareToPlay()
                sound.play()
            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

        } else {
            print("Could not find resource!")
        }

    }

}
```

I put up a full (simple) example project here: https://github.com/DonMag/TestMP3

---

*The following is based on usage within an iOS app*

Make sure your `AVAudioPlayer` object is not declared where you are trying to play your sound. It will go out-of-scope before it can actually play the audio.

Here is a current way to play a sound, for example on a button tap:

```
// declared at class-level
var sound = AVAudioPlayer()

@IBAction func didTap(_ sender: Any) {

    // abort with error message if this.mp3 is not found in the bundle
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "this", withExtension: "mp3") else {
        fatalError("Could not get URL for mp3 file!")
    }

    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

        sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)

        sound.play()

    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}
```

---

**Edit**

If this code stops and prints `Could not get URL for mp3 file!` to the debug console, then your mp3 file is **not** being included in the bundle.

Select it in Project Navigator and make sure it has your target **checked** under `Target Membership` in the File Inspector pane. Also check under:

- Project Settings
- Build Phases
- Copy Bundle Resources

and make sure it's listed there.

---

**Edit 2**

Assuming you are running this on Simulator...

Add these two lines before `guard let url - ...`:

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Info", ofType: ".plist")
print(path)
```

That should print a long path that looks something like this:

```
/Users/yourname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C55189E0-FDC2-4D93-A1DA-D52EF2EAE905/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F50C01D1-FF99-4592-8569-120E7362E23B/xcodeProject.app/Info.plist
```

Copy that path, go to a Finder window, select `Go -> Go to Folder...` and paste in that whole path. Look at the files found there, and see if your `this.mp3` exists.

If it doesn't, then remove `this.mp3` from your project and add it back in again and give it another try.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your response. I did make changes to address the scoping issue. After running the code, I'm getting ""Could not get URL for mp3 file!" Please let me know if you would like a screenshot of the project directory, but the path to mp3 file is as follows: /Desktop/Project/xcodeProject/files/this.mp3

Comment: Thanks for your swift response. I checked all those parts. All the criteria you mentioned is satisfied. Still not able to play the sound

Comment: @farzan = are you running this on Device or Simulator?

Comment: @farzan - I gave you a couple more instructions in **Edit 2**

Comment: Hi DonMag, Followed your instructions, it gave the same error (e.g. Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file) -> referring to line _print(path)_ Also, I made this project as a command line application on Xcode.

Comment: OK - sounds like something is wrong with your build configuration / process.

Comment: Oh wait... *”command line application”*? Then that may be a completely different issue.

Comment: @farzan - check the **Edit 3** part of my answer (now at the top)... I didn't realize you were building a Command Line Application.